# Spring Data doesn't update with save() method

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently working on an application for an university project. For this project, my team and I are using a Vaadin/Spring/Maven configuration. With this we also include a database connected with repositories.

The repositories are build the following way. First a class for objects:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table (name = "component")
public class Component {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    String name;
    float price;
    boolean isVegetarian;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<InvoicePosition> Positions;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    ComponentCategory category_id;
    String path;

public Component() {
}

public Component(String name, float price, boolean isVegetarian, ComponentCategory category, String path) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.isVegetarian = isVegetarian;
    this.category_id = category;
    this.path = path;
}
```

Then the additional repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ComponentRepository extends JpaRepository<Component, Long>{}
```

Then there is a repository for component category, in which we should be able to store a list of components:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "componentCategory")
public class ComponentCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Component> components;

public ComponentCategory() {    }

public ComponentCategory(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    components = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addComponentToCategory(Component component) {
    if(!components.contains(component))
    {
        components.add(component);
        component.category_id = this;
    }
}
```

And then the same repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ComponentCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ComponentCategory, Long> {}
```

I am able to create new entries and they are also properly stored in the database. This is all stored in the Application.Java file to start the Vaadin application

```
ComponentCategory cat1 = new ComponentCategory("examp1");
Component test1 = new Component("example1", 1.25f, true, cat1, "");
Component test2 = new Component("example2", 0.89f, true, cat1, "");
cat1.addComponentToCategory(test1);
cat1.addComponentToCategory(test2);
compcatrep.saveAndFlush(comp); // compcatrep is the ComponentCategoryRepository, which is passed on to the init() function
```

Now I'm trying to update the entries in the database with the following logic:

```
 Component test11 = new Component("Test", 2.15f, true, compcatrep.getOne((long)4), "");
 ComponentCategory comp = compcatrep.getOne((long)4);
 comp.addComponentToCategory(test11);
 compcatrep.saveAndFlush(comp);
```

I made sure that there is an entry with the ID (long) 4. It does work and does not show me any error, when I execute the application. Also if I check the length of the stored list in the `ComponentCategory` after the `saveAndFlush()`:

```
System.out.println(comp.getComponents().size());       
System.out.println(compcatrep.getOne((long)4).getComponents().size());
```

I do receive different length of the lists. The second Syso does show one less then the first. I tried a lot and did not find the error. Some more information about my issue:

ApplicationProperties in target folder:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./mensarioDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

POM.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.hs-augsburg.bpap</groupId>
    <artifactId>mensario</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mensario</name>
    <description>mensario management</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.1.0</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to relate to vaadin, so you might be getting more help if you find title that shows you need help with Spring Data JpaRepository.